# Value cannot be null (exception)

Tags: c#, file, listbox, null

I was not experiencing this error when all of the sudden it comes up - no idea why. I have tried resolving it but nothing works. The error occurs at "          genreList.Items.AddRange(trackList);" (the last line of code). Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
    private void readFile()
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(>path<);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 2)
            {
                media[0, 0] = lines[i]; // General (title)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[0, 0]); // Debug, checking values in array after each 'if'
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                media[0, 1] = lines[i]; // Introduction.wma (list)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[0, 1]);
            }
            if (i == 5)
            {
                media[1, 0] = lines[i]; // Setup (title)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[1, 0]);
            }
            if (i == 6)
            {
                media[1, 1] = lines[i]; // Calling Setup.wma (list)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[1, 1]);
            }
            if (i == 8)
            {
                media[2, 0] = lines[i]; // Hint & Tips (title)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[2, 0]);
            }
            if (i == 9)
            {
                media[2, 1] = lines[i]; // Big Bad John (1961) - Jimmy Dean.mp3 (list)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[2, 1]);
            }
            if (i == 10)
            {
                media[2, 2] = lines[i]; // My Ding A Ling - Chuck Berry.mp3 (list)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[2, 2]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void populateGenreList()
    {
        genreTitle.Text = media[0, 0];
        string[] trackList = new string[3];
        trackList[0] = media[0, 1];
        genreList.Items.AddRange(trackList);
    }
```

Comment: tracklist will be null.. EDIT: Also, as a favour to programming and yourself, use a [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid adding values that contain null while using AddRange

```
trackList[0] = media[0, 1];
if(trackList != null)
{
        genreList.Items.AddRange(trackList);
}
```

Comment: tracklist is not null. also you can add a list with null values to a list using addrange, unless it is an extended List.

Answer (score 0):

In this line,

```
genreList.Items.AddRange(trackList);
```

the **trackList** is not null since you're just initializing it a line ago. Also, you can add a list containing null values using the AddRange method. so trackList could have 3 null values and still you shouldn't see the null reference.

But this happens to List AddRange method.

So in your case, there is some custom code that is creating this exception. Definition of genreList class and stack trace of the exception, please.

Comment: Cheers for the answer. I changed the code to
            try
            {
                genreList.Items.AddRange(trackList);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               
            }

and it works now ;) Cheers again

Comment: what is the definition of the genereList class? why are you getting a null reference? with the code posted in the question, you shouldn't be unless genreList is your class which is throwing some sort of ArgumentNullException..

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'definition'.
string[,] media = new string[4, 3]; -This is how I declare it.